# dropdownlist not showing data properly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

i have this dropdown list which get the data from db but does not display the data properly n the view

The codes are as follows:

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> Model.SystemRAteModel.Role, new SelectList(Model.SystemRAteModel.GetRole.Items),"Value","Text")
```

Model:

```
public class SystemRolesModel
    {
        public static RoleProvider Provider { get; internal set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public   String Role { get; set; }
        public   Boolean Status { get; set; }
        public SelectList GetRole { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IApplicationLogic app = new ApplicationLogic(session);
            RateManagementModel RTM = new RateManagementModel();
            var value = app.GetVatValue();
            var freight = app.GetFreightValue();
         //   var systemrolemodel = new SystemRolesModel();
            //var currency = new List<SelectList>();
            //   currency= app.GetListOfRoles();
            //IList<string> ERModel = new List<string>();
            //foreach (var _currency in currency)
            //{
            //    var curent = _currency.ToString();
            //    ERModel.Add(curent);
            //}

            var sysmodel = new SystemRolesModel();
            sysmodel.GetRole = getRoleSelectList();
            RTM.SystemRAteModel = sysmodel;

            ViewData["ViewVatValue"] = value;
            //ViewData["ViewCurrency"] = new SelectList(currency);

            //ViewBag.LocationList = freight;
            ViewData["ViewFreightValue"] = freight;
            return View("Index",RTM);
        }

        public SelectList getRoleSelectList()
        {
            IApplicationLogic app = new ApplicationLogic(session);
            var roles = app.GetListOfRoles();

            SystemRoles sr = new SystemRoles();
            sr.Id = -1;
            sr.Role = "--select role--";
            roles.Add(sr);

            IEnumerable<SystemRoles> sortedRoles = roles.OrderBy(d => d.Id);
            IList<SystemRoles> _sortedRoles = sortedRoles.ToList();
            return new SelectList(_sortedRoles, "Id", "Role");
        }
```

i have tried everything on the net but cant get a hand on it. Please any help will do.[OutPut of my System At the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o7PX.png)

Comment: You've used SystemRAteModel. I think that is not in your code. Is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new `SelectList` again in View, as you are already creating that in controller side and passing it via Model, you should be able to directly use it in View like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> Model.SystemRAteModel.Role,Model.SystemRAteModel.GetRole)
```

This should populate the dropdown with the values, but it would display same values for all the items for now, as your code is setting hard-coded same values for all properties here:

```
SystemRoles sr = new SystemRoles();
sr.Id = -1;
sr.Role = "--select role--";
roles.Add(sr);
```

You would need to change it to have proper values.

Another easy way can be to use the constructor of `SelectList` this way:

```
public SelectList getRoleSelectList()
{
     IApplicationLogic app = new ApplicationLogic(session);
     var roles = app.GetListOfRoles().OrderBy(x=> x.RoleID);

     return new SelectList(roles.ToList(), "RoleID", "Role");
}
```

you will just need to replace `RoldID` and `Role` property name with the proerty names you have in the DTO.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @Ehsan it worked marvelously, was just making a simple mistake of putting the new selectlist tag and removing it just cured it all.

Comment: glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name", Model.Select(modelItem => new SelectListItem
                                                                       {
                                                                           Text = modelItem.Name,
                                                                           Value = modelItem.Id.ToString(),
                                                                           Selected = modelItem.Id == "12314124"
                                                                       }))
```

Comment: Model - IEnumerable<something>